# How to deduce function type in SML

Tags: sml

I have a `foo` function defined as follows

```
fun foo x y = x (x (x y));
```

How to deduce the function type?

The answer is:

```
val foo = fn : ('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This process is called [type inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference) which is done in SML by [Hindley–Milner algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner).

First let's start with a generic type signature for `foo`:

```
val foo = fn : 'c -> 'b -> 'a
```

where `x` has type `'c` and `y` has type `'b`.

We have the following steps:

- `x y` is function application, `x` should have signature `'b -> 'd` and we have an equation `'c = 'b -> 'd` and `x y` has type `'d`.
- `x (x y)` means we apply a function type `'b -> 'd` on an argument type `'d` so  `'d = 'b` and `'c = 'b -> 'b`.
- `x (x (x y))` means we apply a function type `'b -> 'b` on an argument type `'b` and return `'a` (type of `foo`); it suffices `'b = 'a`.
- after unification, we have `'c = 'a -> 'a and 'b = 'a` and `foo` has a generic type: `val foo = fn : ('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a`